# Partial pressure problem

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, physical-chemistry

Recently while reading the literature that ethyl alcohol has a higher partial pressure than water, thereby having a tendency to evaporate and be lost.'

My understanding is that the higher the partial pressure, the harder it is to evaporate, but it is written here that there is a tendency to evaporate, I would like to ask the possible reason.

[image]

Comment: Did you mean “vapor pressure?”

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please type your question and if you need to include material from another source, type that too (with a quote box) instead of pasting an image of the text. Typed text is easier to read, possible to edit, and possible to search. Images of text are none of those things and especially in this case the image is really hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

At a liquid-vapor interface, liquid molecules are constantly leaving the surface to enter the vapor phase, and vapor molecules are constantly adhering to the surface to return to the liquid phase. These two processes reach equilibrium when the “partial pressure” of the substance above the liquid is equal to the “vapor pressure” of the liquid at the temperature of the interface.

For example, when the partial pressure of water vapor in air exceeds the vapor pressure of liquid water, the water vapor will condense out of the air as dewdrops.  This is also why sweating becomes ineffective for thermal management when the humidity is too high.  A useful homework problem is to compute the partial pressures which correspond to “100% relative humidity” at a few temperatures, and compare to the vapor pressure curve for water.

Your source (which is screeenshotted but not linked) seems to confuse these terms.  “Vapor pressure” is a property of a material. “Partial pressure” is a property of your environment.  You can reduce the partial pressure of ethanol above a surface by replacing the air there with fresh, alcohol-free air from outside; the ethanol will then evaporate until the vapor above the surface is saturated.

The boiling temperature is where the vapor pressure becomes equal to the atmospheric pressure, so that liquid would still enter the vapor phase even if *all* of the pressure at the surface came from the vapor.

Comment: At the boiling temperature, bubbles of pure vapor can begin forming below the surface.

Comment: Better to say that *above* the boiling temperature, the vapor pressure is large enough that bubbles of vapor tend to grow rather than shrink. The *formation* of the vapor bubbles is a surprisingly complicated problem; [see e.g. this answer about a kitchen experiment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/557826/44126) which was inspired by the behavior of a cryostat.